# Stored procedures to populate Mysql db using a CSV file

Tags: mysql

Working with Mysql, are stored procedures suitable for populating 6 different tables belonging to a database?

Data is listed in a CSV file.

By the way should I have 6 different CSV files or just a single one?

My idea is that I'd like to avoid the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command.

Thanks very much

Mauro

Comment: Why would you like to avoid LOAD DATA INFILE?

Comment: Please explain you you would want to avoid MySQL's greatest and fastest (!) import feature, just to roll your own slow and complicated knockoff.

Comment: Use 1 CSV per table, that way the mapping is straightforward, I recommend use LOAD DATA INFILE inside the stored procedure BTW.

Comment: Actually it's all part of a project and I would get a better score if I used stored procedures ...

Comment: @Johan LOAD DATA INFILE cannot be used within a stored procedure.

Comment: @f00, use `load data local infile` instead

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a good idea becouse it would be plataform dependent, and you can't check important things from SP. I'd consider bash scripting.

Comment: So I can actually use stored procedures to populate a database and I should use the LOAD DATA INFILE command for every single csv file ..am I right?

Comment: Yes, but you'd tie the parameters into the scritps. It's not such a good idea. For example, the paths to the files. Those would be frozen into the SP. I'd do some bash script. The Operating System is better suited for handling files, permissions, etc